# Why is Jquery not working when the entire page is reloaded with Ajax Response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I am forced to do a reload of the entire web page through the Ajax success response. I am currently using .html function, though not ideal I need the entire page to be reloaded since I cannot control the response. I even tried document.write.

However, after reloading the page the javascript stops working on the form which is dynamically rendered. I checked and the following solutions such as .on or innerHTML do not apply since I am refreshing the entire page. Can I do the entire page reload using any other way or force javascript to load the form that is created dynamically?

My current code -

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'visaMatrix.php',
    data: $('#<?php echo $template_form_id ?>').serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
        //Display the result on the entire web page. 
        $('#modalLoading').modal('hide');
        $("html").html(response);
    },
    error: function(response){
        $(".loadingContainer").html("Looks like we had a problem. Please close the window and try again.");
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using ajax then?

Comment: Well, the response takes a finite time at the server end and I want to display the user a loading modal while that happens.

Comment: I added a downvote, not because of your question but your solution. Replace entire HTML will also remove all `eventListener` that was binded when you load the page ( first time).
 To explain it easier, it sounds like you replace a painting, which was painted by hand very detail with a printed hard photo, which cannot modify.

Comment: There must be a better way than what you have at the moment, perhaps [location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) or redirecition to another page after the request

Comment: Yes, I think I understand now, @AlonEitan I shouldnt be using Ajax in the first place for this. Thank you. I tried using submit which loads the page directly than me loading it using Ajax. I was not sure if I could display the loading screen but it is working though page gets refreshed but I can live with that. Thank you.

Comment: @Kai - I understand now how this works. Thank you.

Comment: @PreethamKamath Perhaps [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/) would be relevant